# How the below program is possible in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I came with a situation where the method of class A to be called from class B.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def abc(self):
        print self.a

class B(A):
    def  __init__(self):
        super(B, self).abc()

def method1():
    a = A(2)

method1()
b = B()

Expecting Output: 2
```

Is it possible to call method 'abc' from class B with changing class A and should not create class A object in class B. If yes, then please let me know the solution.

The above program which I tried is giving error.

And the error I am getting is below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "a.py", line 12, in <module>
       b = B()
   File "a.py", line 10, in __init__
       super(B, self).abc()
File "a.py", line 6, in abc
   print self.a
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Comment: What do you expect this to print, considering `a` is not initialized to anything?

Comment: `self.a` is defined in `A`'s `__init__()` function. Since you are overriding `__init__()` in `B`, `self.a` is not defined in `B`.

Comment: You need to call `super(A,  self).__init__(...)` to ensure that all attributes are set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your B class __init__ method is not taking any argument, while the __init__ of class A require you to pass one (named "a"), and yet, you are not providing it. Neither in your B class or by passing it to A.

However, this would work.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def abc(self):
        print self.a

class B(A):
    def  __init__(self):
        self.a = 10
        super(B, self).abc()
```

Or:

```
class B(A):
    def  __init__(self):
       super(B, self).__init__(10)

inst = B()
inst.abc() # 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
class B(A):
    def  __init__(self):
        super(B, self).abc()
```

The constructor of `A` is never called, so the initialization done in `A.__init__` is missing. It fails in `print self.a`, because there is no `a`.
The super constructor should be called.

Furthermore, `super(B, self).abc()` is the same as `self.abc()`.

If there was a method named `abc` defined in `B`, then `self.abc()` would call the method from `B`, whereas `super(B, self).abc()` would call the method from the superclass.

So, since those are the same, I would not use the ugly one. It just makes the code less readable.

With those two fixes:

```
class B(A):
    def  __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__(1000)  # whatever default value
        self.abc()
```